# A quadrant of residues

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

Assume that following inequality holds $$\mathsf{w,x,y,z<AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD<ABC,ABD,ACD,BCD<wx,wy,wz,xy,xz,yz}$$ with $$\mathsf{gcd(A,B)=gcd(A,C)=gcd(A,D)=gcd(B,C)=gcd(B,D)=gcd(C,D)=1}$$

where we know $\mathsf{A,B,C,D}$ and we have following residue values: 
$$\mathsf{xz\bmod A,\quad wz\bmod C}$$
$$\mathsf{xy\bmod B,\quad wy\bmod D}$$

Is there a standard procedure to find $\mathsf{w,x,y,z}$?

Only standard procedure I can think of is exhaustive search which needs $\mathsf{(ABCD)^2}$ arithmetic operations. Is there a way to do this is say at most $\mathsf{(ABCD)^{\frac{1}\beta-\epsilon}}$ arithmetic operations where $\epsilon\in(0,\frac{1}\beta)$ with $\beta>2$ holds?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question either - just upvoted. Isn't it a bit strange to express the number of steps in terms of the unknowns? Is there a particular reason that you interested in the threshold $(wxyz)^{\frac 14-\epsilon}$ rather than something else?

Comment: I am assuming here $w,x,y,z$ are equal sizes which seems to be hardest case. For unequal cases, it seems plausible we can get $\beta=3$ so I am thinking may be $\beta=4$ is case to be seen.

Comment: I could have used $(ABCD)^2$ instead of $wxyz$.

Comment: So that would seem to be a much tidier formulation.

Comment: Ok I will change.

Comment: This is a method I tried for this problem and am not successful so far http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215999/mathsfgcd-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: What is frustrating is guessing any pairs is still insufficient.

Comment: I think you can solve in $O( (AB)^2)$ or similar distinct square of two distinct.

Comment: @joro could you give the procedure?

Comment: Hm, I noticed mistake in my current approach.

Comment: Does the tag indicate that this subject is to be studied by @TheoJohnson-Freyd?

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer giving probabilistic algorithm under
assumptions which can be greatly relaxed.

wlog assume $AB$ is the smallest product.

Write
$$ r_1= xz \mod A \qquad (1)$$
$$ r_2= xy \mod B \qquad (2)$$
$$ r_3= wz \mod C \qquad (3)$$
$$ r_4= wy \mod D \qquad (4)$$

Assume $r_1r_2$ is coprime to $AB$ and $r_3$ is coprime to $C$ and
$r_4$ is coprime $D$.

Iterate $x_1$ from $1$ to $AB$.

Try to compute $z_1=r_1 x_1^{-1} \mod AB$ from (1)
and $y_1=r_2 x_1^{-1} \mod AB$ from (2).

$(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ satisfy (1) and (2) and the required inequality.

Try to compute $w_1'=r_3 z_1^{-1}\mod C$ and $w_2'=r_4 y_1^{-1} \mod D$

Apply the Chinese remainder theorem to $w_1' \mod C,w_2' \mod D$
to get $w_1 \mod CD$.

If $w_1 < AB$, $(x_1,y_1,z_1,w_1)$ is solution.

The complexity is $O(AB)$.

The main source of possible failure is the last step.